# Tensorflow WarmStartSettings embedding shape mismatch

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the new [`tf.estimator.WarmStartSettings`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/WarmStartSettings) to initialize my network from a previous checkpoint. I now want to run the same network on a new data source, with other vocabs to use for the embeddings.

This snippet from the [documentation page of WarmStartSettings](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/WarmStartSettings) seems to describe my use case:

> Warm-start all weights but the embedding parameters corresponding to
>   sc_vocab_file have a different vocab from the one used in the current
>   model:
>
> ```
> vocab_info = ws_util.VocabInfo(
>     new_vocab=sc_vocab_file.vocabulary_file,
>     new_vocab_size=sc_vocab_file.vocabulary_size,
>     num_oov_buckets=sc_vocab_file.num_oov_buckets,
>     old_vocab="old_vocab.txt"
> )
> ws = WarmStartSettings(
>     ckpt_to_initialize_from="/tmp",
>     var_name_to_vocab_info={
>         "input_layer/sc_vocab_file_embedding/embedding_weights": vocab_info
>     })
> ```

[`tf.estimator.VocabInfo`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/VocabInfo) allows to specify the old and new vocab with their respective sizes. However, when I try to use the WarmStartSettings as shown above with 2 vocabs of different sizes, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Shape of variable input_layer/sc_vocab_file_embedding/embedding_weights
>   ((1887, 30)) doesn't match with shape of tensor
>   input_layer/sc_vocab_file_embedding/embedding_weights ([537, 30]) from checkpoint reader.

Why does VocabInfo allow to provide separate sizes for the vocabs if their size has to match anyway?

Comment: Any update on this? I've got the same problem